# UWP C++/WinRT - How to detect whether right mouse button is pressed

Tags: uwp, mouse, c++-winrt

I intend to implement a mouse "dragging" gesture in my application, following the PointerPressed() / PointerMoved() / PointerReleased() pattern. This is a UWP application using the recently released C++/WinRT language projection for Windows.

Thing is, I need to do it using the right mouse button, instead of the left mouse button.

The Pointer****() events currently do not offer a way to know which button was pressed. If you attempt to do a call to GetKeyState() inside the Pointer****() events, the ::RightButton virtual key will always return 0 (None). Also, the RightTapped() event will not fire until the button is released.

Yet, if you attach a PointerPressed() event to a Button (in addition to a Click() event), you will notice that left clicks will fire the Click event, while right clicks will actually fire the PointerPressed() event. So, in theory, it *is* possible to distinguish between the two mouse buttons (since the API already does it).

Anybody know a way to perform the gesture above in a UWP C++/WinRT application using the right mouse button? Any suggestion will do, I'm currently at my wits end.

Comment: any reason you are not using `Drag***` events for your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `IsRightButtonPressed` value of `PointerPointProperties` which can be accessed through `PointerRoutedEventArgs`. Say you get `PointerRoutedEventArgs e` as parameter in event handler, then

```
PointerPoint currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(NULL);
PointerPointProperties props = currentPoint.Properties();
if (props.IsRightButtonPressed()) {
    // right button pressed!
}
```

You can check this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/handle-pointer-input#pointer-event-example) for more details which is in C#. Check `GetCurrentPoint` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs.getcurrentpoint#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_PointerRoutedEventArgs_GetCurrentPoint_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_) regarding which parameter to pass as argument

Comment: Actually, I want to amend my previous statement. Yes, you were right all along. There *is* a IsRightButtonPressed() property in PointerPoint.Properties(). And it works, I just tested it. Thanks a millon for the help!

Comment: … although, I think the absence of parentheses at the end of .Properties and .IsRightButtonPressed reveals that the code above is actually not C++/WinRT, but C++/CX (I think?)

Comment: @Izhido thanks for pointing it out, I missed it. Parentheses are required here :)

Comment: @Izhido just for general information... as per my experience so far UWP `C#` APIs always match with `C++/WinRT`, just need to properly use it